# How to extract a double quote field in regex that start with a specific string

Tags: regex

I'd like to extract the name content (David) and the url content (www.stackoverflow.com) from the following json file.

I have several questions:

How to extract a string that starts with " and ends with " ?

Hoe to force the regular expression to start with an expression that is not part of the matching regular expressing.

```
{
   "id" : "1234",
   "name" : "David",
   "request" :  {
       "url" : "www.stackoverflow.com",
       "method" : "POST",
       "bodyPatterns" : [ {
          "matchesXPath" : "example"
    }, {
          "matchesXPath" : "example/123"
    }, {
   "matchesXPath" : {
   "expression" : "example/123/123/text()",
   "equalTo" : "bbbb"
    }
    } ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend using a JSON parser rather than Regex. It will be a lot more readable and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: a proper parser is the most recommended way to do this on the long term. For a simple, occasional situation regex might fit.

---

This regex does the job:

```
"name"\s*:\s*"(?'name'[^"]+)".*"url"\s*:\s*"(?'url'[^"]+)"
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/d3AQqB/1). Groups `name` and `url` contain your data.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend solving this with a regular expression. Such ad-hoc parsing solutions tend to be error-prone, overly complicated, hard to extend and turn on you when you least expect it.

Instead, I recommend using a proper json parser, depending on the language you use. For plain shell, `jq` is a good choice. With that, specifying the path to the property becomes trivial:

```
cat file.json | jq '.request.url'
```